# Efficient conditional rolling calculation Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series, rolling-computation

Generating the data

```
random.seed(42)
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(len(date_rng))),
                  columns=['data'],
                 index= date_rng)
mask = np.random.choice([1, 0], df.shape, p=[.35, .65]).astype(bool)
df[mask] = np.nan
```

I want to calculate `std()` for rolling with windows = 5, if more than half of the elements in the windows = NaN, the rolling calculation is equal to NaN, if less than half of the elements in the windows = NaN, dropna() and calculate std() for the rest of the elements.

I only know how to calculate normal rolling:

```
df.rolling(5).std()
```

How could I specify the conditon of the rolling calculation

Comment: can you add date_rng or a portion of it

Comment: my bad, I will add it

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the argument `min_periods` in the `rolling function`

```
df['rollingstd'] = df.rolling(5, min_periods=3).std()
df.head(20)


Out put:
                     data  rollingstd
2018-01-01 00:00:00   1.0         NaN
2018-01-01 01:00:00   6.0         NaN
2018-01-01 02:00:00   1.0    2.886751
2018-01-01 03:00:00   NaN    2.886751
2018-01-01 04:00:00   5.0    2.629956
2018-01-01 05:00:00   3.0    2.217356
2018-01-01 06:00:00   NaN    2.000000
2018-01-01 07:00:00   NaN         NaN
2018-01-01 08:00:00   3.0    1.154701
2018-01-01 09:00:00   NaN         NaN
2018-01-01 10:00:00   5.0         NaN
2018-01-01 11:00:00   9.0    3.055050
2018-01-01 12:00:00   NaN    3.055050
2018-01-01 13:00:00   9.0    2.309401
2018-01-01 14:00:00   1.0    3.829708
2018-01-01 15:00:00   0.0    4.924429
2018-01-01 16:00:00   3.0    4.031129
2018-01-01 17:00:00   0.0    3.781534
2018-01-01 18:00:00   1.0    1.224745
2018-01-01 19:00:00   NaN    1.414214
```

Comment: I want to add a little more to the question, what if instead of regulating with `np.nan`, I want the rolling return NaN if half of the value in the windows is 0, then how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative more custom method :

**Write a custom method for your logic which taken an array of window size elements as input and return the wanted result for that window:**

```
def cus_mean(x):
    notnone = ~(np.isnan(x))
    if notnone.sum()>2:
        return np.mean([y for y in x if ~(np.isnan(y))])
```

Then call the rolling function on your dataframe as below:

```
 df.rolling(5).apply(cus_mean)
```

Comment: in small example, forloop implementation is OK, but I think it's not efficient for large dataset

Comment: Ok so for loop only works for the elements in window size, so its a constant operation, it won't depend on size of data. 2. Its the way to go if you have to do something very customised for a particular use case. For your use case, using min_periods with rolling would work.